# Why does `SELECT count(*)` return 1?

Tags: performance, optimization, query-performance

Some RDBMS's seem to allow a query without a FROM clause, eg:

```
postgres=# SELECT 'foo' bar;
┌─────┐
│ bar │
├─────┤
│ foo │
└─────┘
```

But for those that allow it, why would `SELECT count(*)` not return 0?

```
postgres=# SELECT count(*);
┌───────┐
│ count │
├───────┤
│     1 │
└───────┘
```

Answer (score 7):

Speaking for PostgreSQL, I found this question to be somewhat interesting.

## Omitted FROM Clauses

This isn't at all permitted in the SQL spec. PostgreSQL calls this feature an ["Omitted FROM clause"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html), and says this about it

> PostgreSQL allows one to omit the FROM clause. [...] Some other SQL databases cannot do this **except by introducing a dummy one-row table from which to do the SELECT.** Note that if a FROM clause is not specified, the query cannot reference any database tables.

Here is what isn't explicit. PostgreSQL is simply **introducing an implicit one-row dummy table for you**. The example of the syntax is `SELECT 2+2` so you can see it's only really made for trivial cases.

```
# SELECT count(*);
 count 
-------
     1
```

This makes sense so long as you remember that it's operating on an implicit dummy table.

```
CREATE TABLE dummy_table ();
INSERT INTO dummy_table DEFAULT VALUES;

SELECT count(*) FROM dummy_table;
```