# dual table postgres doesn't return timestamp

Tags: postgresql, select, timestamp, system-tables

I am trying to select now() from my local postgres database dual table:

```
select now() from dual;
```

It returns no rows. Just prints column name `now(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff)`

What is it that I am missing that it cannot get the system time?

Answer (score 7):

## Don't create `dual` tables

Why are you using a dual table in PostgreSQL to begin with? PostgreSQL has an implicit dual table if there is no from-clause.

```
SELECT now(); -- works fine.
```

You can also

```
SELECT * FROM now(); -- works fine.
```

- For more information, see my answer to [*Why does `SELECT count(*)` return 1?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159775/2639)

## Creating a `dual` table should still work

You'll never need a dual table with PostgreSQL, and you shouldn't create one: it just convolutes the syntax. It's also foreign for most PostgreSQL users. That said, it's easy to demonstrate that it works..

```
test=# CREATE TABLE dual AS ( VALUES (true) );
SELECT 1
test=# SELECT now() FROM dual ;
              now              
-------------------------------
 2017-10-05 15:34:34.359092-05
(1 row)
```